# Problem set of modal logic with solution

Tags: reference-request, modal-logic

I am reading the the book "modal logic" of Blackburn to learn modal logic. But I cannot find the solution of this textbook online. Could someone here tell me if there is some online resource of problem sets of modal logic with solutions which regards similar topics discussed in Blackburn?

Thanks you.

Comment: As far as I know, there are no solutions available for the blue book. However, some of the exercises from the book were solved here (modal-logic tag).

Comment: Also, there are some solutions available in van Benthem's Modal Logic for Open Minds